# How to make a HttpWebRequest function Async?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to make my function async. How would I go about this? Its a HttpWebRequest

```
private void PostToGoogleChat(string json)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_chatUrl);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: "How to make  a HttpWebRequest function async" : by using HttpClient instead.

Comment: Use HttpClient  instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: There is no reason to still use WebRequest et al in new code in Core 3.

Comment: `var httpResponse = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();` but don't use it. Use HttpClient instead. A request is neither sync or async, it's just a request object. *Getting a response* needs to be sync or async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();  

public async Task PostAsync(string actionName, object json)
{
        var content = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
        var resultRoles = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(actionName),content);
}
```

You're new so I wont go into detail about HttpClient, but the instance should be reused. Try to do some self research on how this should be accomplished.

Comment: HttpClient should be static. Per the docs. "It is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.0

Comment: @WilliamXifaras - re-used: yes. static: not the only option, and usually not the best.

Comment: It does not need to be "static", but the instance needs to be reused either via singleton, or HttpClientFactory(pooling).

Since hes new, i'm just showing him how to simply make an async request.  I feel it's unnecessary to edit this, since the clients lifetime has nothing to do with making an async request. @WilliamXifaras

Comment: @Going-gone Yeah I like HttpClientFactory over HttpClient.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True and this is debatable, but I won't do it here. Thinking about it, since its .NET Core, I'd opt for using HttpClientFactory.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use HttpWebRequest, the closest to async workflow would look something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest;

void BeginWebRequest()
{
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(EndWebRequest),null);
}

void EndWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    webRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
}
```

The code above uses the old "callback" style approach for async communication. The result of your request will be received through EndWebRequest method.

That said, you should consider switching to HttpClient since it supports the far easier "async -> await" syntax.

Comment: And with [`TaskFactory.FromAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=netframework-4.8) you could turn this into a handsome awaitable method. But still not as good as using HttpClient.